# Emacs menu bar functions

Tags: emacs

I want to call function "copy text in region between mark and current position" in menubar of Emacs by key.

How can I know the function names in menubar?
Is there a function like `describe-key` for menubar?

Comment: Yes, it's `describe-key`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use C-h k (`describe-key`) and then click the menu item. That is, `describe-key` works for the menu too.

The keyboard shortcut you're after is probably M-w, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Others have given you the answer (`C-h k`).

But do you not also see the keyboard shortcut next to the menu item, like this: `Copy`          `M-w`?

If you do not, check whether you see it when you start without an init file (`~/.emacs`), that is, using `emacs -Q`.  If you do not, then please report that as a bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.